# Microphone only in Skype not working

Tags: sound, skype

Since an update to Skype 8.11.0.4 the microphone stopped working (also 8.12.76.7 (preview) isn't working). Checked with other applications, e.g. SoundRecorder, where the mic is working nicely.
Now I know that skype is using alsa and my `elementary os` (`$ uname -a` 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 15:57:59 UTC 2017 x86_64) uses `pulseaudio`. Tried the solutions found in ubuntu-forums, like:

- remove `pulseaudio`
- remove the `.config/.pulse`
- use `pavucontrol`
- use `alsamixer`

nothing worked. Any other idea?

Comment: Never remove pulseaudio, if you do that lots of applications that play audio will stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the recent update of my system (including skype) the microphone is working fine again in skype.